# Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element (all form Modules are imported)

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am building a simple front end app with a json server to perform CRUD operations,in the html file it shows this error on the [formGroup]
Property formGroup is not provided by any applicable directives nor by form element
ReactiveFormsModule and FormModule are imported.

**this is the component.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {NgbModal, NgbModalConfig} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng- 
    bootstrap";
  import { FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
  import {KundenModel} from "../Kunden-Model";
  import {CrudService} from "../crud.service";

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-kunden-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './kunden-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kunden-dashboard.component.css'],
    })
 export class KundenDashboardComponent implements OnInit {


 formvalue: FormGroup;
 kundenObj: KundenModel=new KundenModel();
 constructor(private formbuilder:FormBuilder, config: NgbModalConfig, private 
 modalService: NgbModal,private api: CrudService) {
 config.backdrop = 'static';
 config.keyboard = false;
 }


 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initializeForm();
 }
 initializeForm(): void {
  this.formvalue = this.formbuilder.group({
   Id: '',
   Name: '',
   Vorname: '',
   Email:''
  });

 }
 open(content: any) {
 this.modalService.open(content);
 }
 postDeatails()
 {
  this.kundenObj.id = this.formvalue.value.Id;
  this.kundenObj.Name = this.formvalue.value.Name;
  this.kundenObj.Vorame = this.formvalue.value.Vorame;
  this.kundenObj.Email = this.formvalue.value.Email;
  this.api.postKunden(this.kundenObj);
  }

 onSubmit() {
 console.log(this.kundenObj);
}

}
```

```html
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Kunden Informationen</h4>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]= 'formvalue' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for = "Id">ID</label>
        <input formControlName="Id" type="text"  class="form-control" id="Id"  placeholder="Enter Id">

      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for = "name">Name</label>
        <input formControlName="Name" type="text"   class="form-control" id="name"  placeholder="Enter Name">

      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for = "vorname">Vorname</label>
        <input formControlName="Vorname" type="text"   class="form-control" id="vorname"  placeholder="Enter Vorname">

      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for = "E-Mail address">Email address</label>
        <input formControlName="Email" type="email"  class="form-control" id="E-Mail address"  placeholder="Enter email">

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="postDeatails()">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="add" (click)="open(content)">Kunden hinzufügen</button>
```

**this is the module.ts**

```
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

      import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
      import { KundenDashboardComponent } from './kunden- 
       dashboard/kunden-dashboard.component';
      import { ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
      import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
      import {CrudService} from "./crud.service";
      import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
      import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

      @NgModule({
       declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       KundenDashboardComponent
       ],
       imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         ReactiveFormsModule,
         NgbModule,
         HttpClientModule,
         AppRoutingModule
         ],
         providers: [CrudService],
         bootstrap: [AppComponent]
         })
         export class AppModule { }
```

EDIT: https://stackblitz.com/github/pariyynpp?file=src/app/app.component.ts here is stackBlitz if anyone wants to check the full code

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Shouldn't you also have imported the FormsModule?

Comment: @toxaq I had it on and someone suggested I remove it and I checked the official documentation and it is not necessary